# Adding Together and Humanizing Time in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, methods

I have an Album model and each album has many tracks:

```
#app/models/album.rb
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tracks
end

#app/models/album.rb
class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
end
```

Each individual track has a duration with a model type of time. To display all of the tracks for each album I've set up my show action as follows:

```
#app/controllers/albums_controller.rb
def show
  @tracks = @artist.tracks.all
end
```

**UPDATE: Showing how duration time is stored in my _form.html.erb**

```
#app/views/tracks/_form.html.erb
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :duration %><br>
  <%= f.time_select :duration, include_seconds: true, default: {hour: '00', minute: '01', second: '30'} %>
</div>
```

--

Here's where the problem occurs. I basically want to add together all of the track durations together and display them in a human readable format. So for example an album *Total Runtime* would be 1 hour 13 minutes. My first instinct to add together the durations was to use the inject method:

```
#apps/views/albums/show.html.erb
.
.
.
<% @tracks.inject(0) {|sum, track|  track.duration.to_s(:time) + sum} %>
```

- I end up getting this error: `no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String`
- My second issue is further configuring the `to_s(:time)` method. Tracks usually display themselves as follows: `3:30`, meaning (x)minutes : (x)seconds. Unfortunately `to_s(:time)` limits you to only showing hours and minutes where I only just need minutes and seconds.
- And to finally get the total duration I wasn't entirely sure what would be the best approach in doing so. Is there a way to save outcome of the inject method as a variable called *runtime* and wrap it like this, while removing the *About* text that comes with the `distance_of_time_in_words` method?

`<p><b>Total Runtime:</b><%= runtime.distance_of_time_in_words %></p>`

Comment: How are you storing your time values?  My recommendation would be to store all values in seconds (e.g. a 3:11 track would be 191 seconds), then do the math/formatting in the appropriate models/helpers.

Comment: @thankyour That's sort've what I need help with. I'm storing the time values using the default select boxes that rails provides for time attributes.

Comment: @thankyour Hopefully the form partial I provided above gives you a little better idea.

Comment: @CarlEdwards hmm...I don't think `time_select` is your friend here. You could replace it with a mere `select` and populate the values yourself, or make it a `number_select` and do the math in the model? You could even make it a text field in your view and perform validation (making sure a number was entered) yourself?

Comment: @thankyour Would you be able to give me an example? A lot of this is still new to me.

Comment: @CarlEdwards does your Album model store its own total length? Or are you dynamically calculating that from its constituent albums?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60247/discussion-between-carl-edwards-and-thankyour).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a lengthy example:

#### `app/models/concerns/time_format.rb`

```
# module to contain method used by both Album and Track
module TimeFormat
  extend ActiveSupport::Concerns

  def to_time(total_time)
    minutes, seconds = total_time.to_i.divmod(60)
    return [minutes, seconds]
  end
end
```

#### `app/models/track.rb`

```
class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  include TimeFormat
  belongs_to :album
  attr_accessor :minutes, :seconds
  validates :length, :minutes, :seconds, numericality: {only_integer: true}
  before_update :to_seconds

  minutes, seconds = to_time(length)

  def to_seconds
    length = (minutes * 60) + seconds
  end
end
```

Hopefully this will point you in the right direction:

#### `app/models/album.rb`

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  include TimeFormat
  has_many :tracks
  attr_accessor :length, :minutes, :seconds
  validates :length, :minutes, :seconds, numericality: {only_integer: true}

  def calculate_length
    self.tracks.each do |track|
      length += track.length
    end
  end

  minutes, seconds = to_time(self.calculate_length)

end
```

#### `app/controllers/albums_controller.rb`

```
# If your controller was generated with scaffolding, no need to change the `show` method.
# It should already be loading an album object for you via the `before_action` callback.
# The only thing to make sure is that you change accepted parameters for the create and
# update methods (do the same thing in Tracks if you need to).

def album_params
  params.require(:album).permit(:minutes, :seconds, <other params>...)
end
```

#### `app/views/tracks/_form.html.erb`

```
# You can use this same field in your Album view.

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :minutes %><br>
  <%= f.number_field :minutes  %>
  <%= f.label :seconds %><br>
  <%= f.number_field :seconds %>
</div>
```

I'm not a seasoned Rails developer yet, so there are probably parts in these examples that can be slimmed down, but I hope this conveys general meaning!